# Weighted harmonic mean with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google sheets, I would like to calculate the weighted harmonic mean of two columns named Weight and Value. Using the normal method, I have to add a third column to find Weight/Value and the calculate the W.H.M as SUM(Weight)/SUM(Weight/Value).

[image]

Is there a way to find that value without the extra column?

Comment: Yes, you can divide array by array with arrayformula: =arrayformula(SUM(A2:A5)/SUM(A2:A5/B2:B5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=SUM(A2:A5)/SUM(INDEX(A2:A5/B2:B5))
```

[image]

Comment: You can also utilize lambda helper `MAP()` function like `=SUM(A2:A5)/ SUM(MAP(A2:A5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,y,x/y)))`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach here..

[image: result]

```
=SUM(A2:A5)/SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5,1/B2:B5)
```